# Converting joomla 2x component compatible to joomla 3x

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, custom-component

I am updating Joomla component to Joomla 3x 
but getting error on code.

**Code Line:**

```
$postData = $this->dr_parameters->app->session->get('errorPostData', array() );
```

**Error:**

> 0 Call to a member function get() on null

and

I replaced the

**previous code:**

```
JRequest::get('post');
```

with

**This code:**

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('post');
```

is this correct?

Comment: It depends on what `$this->dr_parameters->app->session` is. If `$this->dr_parameters->app->session` is returning a JRequest object then you need to get whatever populates `$this->dr_parameters->app->session` to populate it with the new object from `JFactory::getApplication()->input`. Or just change that line to `$postData = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('errorPostData', array());`. Did that not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the JSession class to get the session data. Change this line:

```
$postData = $this->dr_parameters->app->session->get('errorPostData', array() );
```

to:

```
$objSession = JFactory::getSession();
$postData = $objSession->get('errorPostData', array());
```

To set a session the value of a session variable, you can do this:

```
$objSession = JFactory::getSession();
$objSession ->set($key, $value);
```

Comment: how can set set session, in previous code i am using this code
 `$this->dr_parameters->app->session->set($key, $new_state);` @itoctopus

Comment: I have updated the answer to include setting a session variable.